# Trying to send data from one class to another class ios (parse)

Tags: ios, parse-platform

sorry if this is really easy or explained already, but I've been looking and while I've been trying different thing's I've read nothing gives me no errors (so I will be able to run the app). I've been attempting to transfer a variable, "recipients", from one class, AddUsersTableViewController, to another class, ComposeViewController. So far I haven't been successful. I'm using Parse and basing this off a PFObject.

Here's my AddUsersViewController, where the 'recipients' property is declared:

```
AddUsersController:

@interface AddUsersViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *recipients;
```

There is a push segue between 'AddUsersViewController' and 'ComposeViewController'. I want to access the variable declaration 'recipients' from AddUsers in 'ComposeViewController, where I want to use it in a method (upload a message). Here's my code:

```
    ComposeViewController:

            -(void)newMessage {
            PFObject *text = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"message"];
            [text setObject:addValues forKey:@"file"];
            [text setObject:self.recipients forKey:@"recipientIds"];
            [text setObject:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId] forKey:@"senderId"];
            [text setObject:[[PFUser currentUser] username] forKey:@"senderName"];
            [text saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)

       }
```

What I'm attempting to do is have the user press on an 'adduser' button attached to and declared on  ComposeViewController, bring up the AddUserViewController (a tableviewcontroller) via segue, select the recipients, dismiss the 'AddUsersViewController' and have my 'ComposeViewController' send the file with the recipients (and recipientIds) attached. Now I know I messed up in some way, but I can't figure out how I can associate the recipients from AddUsers to ComposeViewController. Help, please? Am I on the right path?

Answer (score 2):

First add the `recipients` array to your `ComposeViewController` public interface :

```
@interface ComposeViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *recipients;
// ...

@end
```

Then implement the `-(void)prepareForSegue:sender:` method in your `AddUsersController` controller. It will be called before the segue is performed.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    ComposeViewController *composeViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    composeViewController.recipients = self.recipients;
}
```